# How to make tokenization using hosted checkout way in mastercard gateway payment (mpgs)

Tags: token, payment, tokenize, mastercard

I want to make tokenization , check mpgs documentation from [here](https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/supportedFeatures/pickAdditionalFunctionality/tokenization/tokenization.html?locale=en_US)

- The idea is that I want to have a token that I can use with all purchases
- First step i have successfully make purchase using hosted checkout way , as you know , the hosted check out page is hosted on mastercard , not my server, so i can not be able to see the card details like number or cvv or expire date.
- So , I check out the documentation to generate token , i found this api :

POST:  `https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/59/merchant/{{merchantId}}/token`

[Here is the documentation fot it](https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/operation/Tokenization%3A%20%20Create%20or%20Update%20Token%20(with%20system-generated%20token).html?locale=en_US)

- I want to get token without know the card details(card number..or cvv...) , but this api request it requires to send card details to get the token:

For example:
POST: https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/59/merchant/999000999/token

**Body As Row :**

```
{
"sourceOfFunds": {
    "provided": {
        "card": {
            "expiry": {
                "month": "05",
                "year": "21"
            },
            "number": "5123456789012346"
        }
    },
    "type": "CARD"
}
```

}

**And the Response :**

```
{
"repositoryId": "REP999000999",
"response": {
    "gatewayCode": "NO_VERIFICATION_PERFORMED"
},
"result": "SUCCESS",
"sourceOfFunds": {
    "provided": {
        "card": {
            "brand": "MASTERCARD",
            "expiry": "0521",
            "fundingMethod": "CREDIT",
            "number": "512345xxxxxx2346",
            "scheme": "MASTERCARD"
        }
    },
    "type": "CARD"
},
"status": "VALID",
"token": "9116324659162248",
"usage": {
    "lastUpdated": "2021-04-24T08:17:18.383Z",
    "lastUpdatedBy": "999000999",
    "lastUsed": "2021-04-24T08:17:18.410Z"
},
"verificationStrategy": "NONE"
```

}

As you see from the response , i get on  "token": "9116324659162248" , But what i need is to get that token but without send card details , i want to do that to avoid PCI Compline ,(My bank told me that)

Is there a way to tokenize without send card payments?

Comment: Hi, hope all is well. I am currently using firebase as my backend and im starting the integration process with MPGS, will i be able to accomplish it with firebase or will i be to have a nodeJS express server to do that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a lot of trouble,you can tokenize card details using these steps:

1- First, you should ask you bank to enable the tokenization for your merchant account

2- Visit this [page](https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/supportedFeatures/pickAdditionalFunctionality/paymentSession.html?locale=en_US) and read the documentation from mpgs gateway

3- After the payment process is completely finished using hosted checkout ,the sessionId should be return, so store it,then execute this api :

[image]

Comment: How do you use this token in hosted checkout again for further payments ?? I can successfully generate the token based on session Id, but when i try to use this token next time while generating session or while making payment request , it throws error.

Comment: @Jolly After generating token, you can use it the same way as you do it without hosted integration.
Alternatively, you can provide token in INITIATE_AUTHENTICATION call, in sourceOfFunds.token field